# android studio help brand new project with main activity errors

Tags: java, android

**Just so everyone knows i was able to fix this problem by making a sample project although i have no idea what it did in terms of fixing the problem :/**

I just started using android studio and I just made a new project and my `mainActivity` has errors on all the imports and I don't know how to fix it. Please help! I have tried to go to file > Invalidate Cache > Invalidate and restart. I have looked for countless hours on line to solve this problem and I cannot. I have no idea how to fix this. I am new to Gradle but have made 2 or 3 apps back when it was only able to be made with Eclipse.

This is the activity main file. I have not changed anything.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; //this is one of the errors
//it says that AppCompactActivity cannot be resolved
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_my, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

this is the Gradle file. I also have not touched this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.compeny.project"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
release {
    minifyEnabled false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
}
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
   }
```

Comment: Have you reloaded the Gradle project via the refresh-like button in the Gradle menu?

Comment: try clean and then sync gradle again

Comment: yes i have also tried this sorry that i forgot to add that into the above question.